# Scrolling down both parts of a split-window at the same time in Vim

Tags: vim

Is it possible to scroll down the left and right parts of a vertically split window in Vim? I have two files I would like to compare roughly. Each line of these files looks *almost* the same.

Answer (score 101, accepted):

See the documentation for [scroll-binding](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-binding). You'll need to set this for *each* window that you want bound (e.g. a minimum of 2)

If you're comparing 2 files, however, [vimdiff](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html) may be of more use

Comment: @BrianAgnew Please include the actual code, not just links.

Comment: :set scrollbind in each split window

Answer (score 239):

Go to the first split, and type in

```
:set scrollbind
```

Go to the next one (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>w</kbd>), and do the same.

To disable:

```
:set noscrollbind
```

For more info, check the documentation for scroll binding - http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/scroll.html#scroll-binding

Comment: If you have all the files open, you can also `:windo set scrollbind`, to set it for all splits at once.

Comment: it's nuggets like these that make me wonder why we don't teach this stuff in school

Comment: :set scrollbind!  to toggle

Answer (score 64):

```
:windo set scrollbind
```

will set scrollbind in all windows.

Comment: If you find yourself doing this a lot, it might be useful to have something like `nmap <F5> :windo set scrollbind!<cr>` to toggle scrollbind in all open windows.

Comment: Don’t know why but `scrollbind!` did not work for me, but `invscrollbind` did. A SUPER mapping. Thanks!

Answer (score 16):

From the command line:

```
vim -O file1 file2 -c 'windo set scb!'
```

-O = open side by side.

-c      = what follows in quotes is treated as a vim option.

'windo' = apply to all panels.

'scb'   = shorthand for scrollbind. Saves some typing, but the two are interchangeable.

'!'     = toggle. This way you can use the same command to turn it off later if you choose to.

Answer (score 12):

G'day,

Tried using vimdiff on the two files?

```
vimdiff file1 file2
```

This will give you the scroll binding by default.

Comment: the problem is that all the lines differ, it's starting to be a mess.. The lines are nearly the same but may differ by one character...and I don't want my view to be too much disturbed..thanks though.

Comment: @LB40 you might consider tweaking your colorscheme, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24666558/improve-vimdiff-syntax-highlighting

Answer (score 6):

For posterity, here's what I needed to do, since I didn't start with vimdiff.

I loaded one file. Then :vsp to load the other.

They are pretty different files, but I wanted to see what's common in between them.

So...

```
:set diff
:set diffopt=iwhite
:set scrollbind
```

Comment: You can get all of those for a given buffer (:diff, :diffopt, :scrollbind) in one command with :diffthis in each of the buffers