# Automate synchronized scrolling

Tags: vim, split, scroll

Like said [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1092685/scrolling-down-both-parts-of-a-split-window-at-the-same-time-in-vim) I can open e.g. a second file in `vim` using

```
:vsplit file2.dat
```

and use

```
:set scrollbind
```

to synchronize the scrolling.

Is there a possibility that this is done automatically when I view files with `vsplit`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about a custom command?!

```
:command! -nargs=* -complete=file VBoundSplit setlocal scrollbind | vsplit <args> | setlocal scrollbind
```

Comment: Hi Ingo. This looks promising, can you please explain this a bit for me? Do you put it in `.vimrc` and call it in `vim`?

Comment: Yes, put this into your `~/.vimrc`, and use `:VBoundSplit <file>` instead of `:vsplit <file>`.