# Toggling scrollbind has weird sideeffects

Tags: vim

Inspired by https://stackoverflow.com/a/18466534/42580 I inserted this into my `.vimrc`

```
nmap <F2> :windo set invscrollbind<cr>
```

Hitting `<F2>` successfully toggles scrollbind on and off on all windows. **But** there is some weirdness going on that I would like to understand:

1. Both when turning on and off the focus moves from the currently active window to the one at the lower right corner. I want the focus to stay!
2. If I bind two windows, scroll down one screen and then unbind (with ) I would expect no visual change. But the unfocused window is scrolled back to the position it had before the bind (one screen up). Why and how do I avoid this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your 2nd problem I cannot reproduce.

Your 1st problem is because you used `windo`, `windo` will go through all your windows and execute the command, and at the end leave the focus on the last window. What you can do is move to the previous window after you 've done `windo`.  This `<expr>` map can help:

```
nnoremap  <expr> <F2> ":windo set invscrollbind\<cr>:".winnr()."wincmd w\<cr>"
```

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is not an answer, but maybe solves your problem: this function turns on window syncing like `diff`, but without coloring:

```
let s:sync_win = 0

function SyncWin()

  let nr = winnr()
  let s:sync_win = 1 - s:sync_win

  if ! s:sync_win
    windo set noscrollbind nocursorbind
    exe nr . 'wincmd w'
    return
  endif

  windo set scrollbind cursorbind nowrap
  exe nr . 'wincmd w'
  syncbind
  set scrollopt+=hor

endfunction
```

EDIT: sorry for the short description, but i did not have time.

To use the function put it to the end of your `.vimrc`, open the files that you want to compare in two splits, then:

```
:call SynWin()
```

To turn off syncing, call it again.

Answer (score 0):

**Answer 2**

I was using [this tip](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Avoid_scrolling_when_switch_buffers) in my `.vimrc` to keep the windows from jumping up and down when switching between buffers. But that did somehow conflict with the scrollbinding. I renamed the var and then there was no problems:

```
au BufLeave * if !&diff | let b:URwinview = winsaveview() | endif
au BufEnter * if exists('b:URwinview') && !&diff | call winrestview(b:URwinview) | unlet! b:URwinview | endif
```