# Improve vimdiff syntax highlighting

Tags: vim, vimdiff

When I run `vimdiff` I get a pretty bad syntax highlighting (unreadable):

[image]

Running on MacVim is a little bit better, but still awful.

Is this because of my color scheme (currently using Tomorrow Night)?

If so, is there a way to modify the colours used in `vimdiff` outside the theme, or maybe install another `ftplugin` that supports this better (not sure about this as `set filetype` shows `vim` instead of `diff` or similar)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Its the color scheme. You would need to modify DiffAdd, DiffChange, DiffDelete, and DiffText. These are the standard highlight groups. The diff syntax file also supports more highlight groups. These groups can be found at the bottom of `$VIMRUNTIME/syntax/diff.vim` these default to standard highlight groups. However these colors will only affect the diff filetype.

You can modify the color scheme by using the after directory. Put changes in `~/.vim/after/colorscheme/<colorscheme_name>.vim` these will get sourced after the color scheme is set.

---

(Personally I haven't found any colors I've liked for vimdiff)

Comment: Thanks a lot. Was able to get to something nice.