# How would I extract a single file (or changes to a file) from a git stash?

Tags: git, git-stash

Is it possible to extract a single file or diff of a file from a git stash without popping the stash changeset off?

Answer (score 1595, accepted):

On the [git stash](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-stash) manpage you can read (in the "Discussion" section, just after "Options" description) that:

> A  stash  is  represented  as  a commit whose tree records the state of the
> working directory, and its first parent is the  commit  at  HEAD  when  the
> stash  was  created.

So you can treat stash (e.g. `stash@{0}` is first / topmost stash) as a merge commit, and use:

```
$ git diff stash@{0}^1 stash@{0} -- <filename>
```

Explanation: `stash@{0}^1` means the first parent of the given stash, which as stated in the explanation above is the commit at which changes were stashed away. We use this form of "git diff" (with two commits) because `stash@{0}` / `refs/stash` is a merge commit, and we have to tell git which parent we want to diff against. More cryptic:

```
$ git diff stash@{0}^! -- <filename>
```

should also work (see [git rev-parse](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-parse#_specifying_ranges) manpage for explanation of `rev^!` syntax, in "Specifying ranges" section).

Likewise, you can use [git checkout](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout) to check a single file out of the stash:

```
$ git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>
```

or to save it under another filename:

```
$ git show stash@{0}:<full filename>  >  <newfile>
```

or

```
$ git show stash@{0}:./<relative filename> > <newfile>
```

(*note* that here <full filename> is full pathname of a file relative to top directory of a project (think: relative to `stash@{0}`)).

---

You might need to protect `stash@{0}` from shell expansion, i.e. use `"stash@{0}"` or `'stash@{0}'`.

Comment: This is pretty cool... I didn't _really_ understand how stash worked until I read your answer (which lead me to the git-checkout addition).  I really didn't get that, when you do a stash, git saves TWO commits -- one for the state of the index and one for the state of the working copy which is a merge between the index and the original HEAD.  This explains the odd trees I've seen when I visualize the repository with "gitk --all" when stashes are present.

Comment: Mostly I find the git checkout application to be the best way to accomplish what it is I wanted to do. However I was curious and double-checked `git checkout`'s man page. It cannot drop the file into another location. There is a reference to this in: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888414/git-checkout-older-revision-of-a-file-under-a-new-name/888623#888623

Comment: Note that the `git checkout` approach copies the _exact_ file from the stash -- it doesn't merge it with what's in your working directory like `git stash apply` would. (So if you have any changes from the base the stash was created on, they'll be lost).

Comment: Note that in order for `git stash apply` to merge the changes in a file that has been modified in the work tree since the file was stashed, that file in the work tree must be staged. For auto-merge to work, the same files cannot be modified both in the working copy and in the stashed copy-to-be-merged. Finally, stash apply doesn't remove the item from stash like `git stash pop` would.

Comment: `git diff stash@{0}^1 stash@{0} -- <filename> | patch -p1`

Comment: git checkout "stash@{0}" if you get "fatal: invalid reference: stash@0"

Comment: `git checkout stash@{0} -- <path-to-folder>` can checkout folders too!

Comment: +1 to @isaaclw's answer using `patch -p1`. I had tried `git diff … | git apply` from http://stackoverflow.com/a/15264717/1172352, but that failed with the error "patch does not apply."  I tried `git diff … | patch -p1` instead and it applied the diff from the stash perfectly!

Comment: I had to enclose in double quotes on Windows:  "stash@{0}:<full filename>"

Comment: At least if there is just one item in the stash list, it works fine to type simply `git checkout stash -- <filename>` without the '@{0}' after 'stash'. (It might work with multiple stashed states, too, but I have not tried it and do not know which state would be the default.)

Comment: As per @OttoG's answer, if you're only interested in the most recent stash item, you can omit the `@{0}`

Comment: Really helpful answer. Really liked git checkout stash@{0} -- <path-to-folder>

Comment: Can't use checkout with untracked files.

Comment: `$ git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>` stages the file for commit. Can that be avoided as quite often file is taken from stash just for tests?

Comment: @Danijel with modern Git you can use `$ git restore --worktree --source=stash@{0} -- <filename>`, I think.

Comment: In PowerShell it is necessary to put `stash@{0}` to single quotes or backticks. Thats because curly braces have special meaning in PowerShell. Otherwise you'll get ``error: unknown switch `e'``.

Comment: is there any way to address untracked files in a stash with any of those methods @JakubNarębski? I tried `checkout` which does not find untracked files apparently

Comment: @vrms: **If** you have saved untracked files to stash by using the `--include-utracked`, then the tree with _untracked files_ is available as `stash@{0}^2`, that is _second parent of stash_ (so you can for example use `git checkout 'stash@{0}^2' -- <filename>`). You can see this with `git log --graph --oneline stash`.

Comment: This does not seems to work when trying to unstash an added(untracked) file that exists only in stash. Pathspec did not match any files known to git.

Comment: @MatJ try `git show 'stash@{0}^2':<filename>` (and try `git ls-tree -r 'stash@{0}^2'` to check if file name is correct).

Comment: @JakubNarębski, I actually missed your previous comment about untracked files. Command in your comment works. I actually got the same command after trying out the git-stash vs code extension.

Answer (score 97):

```
$ git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>
```

Notes:

1. Make sure you **put space after the "--"** and the file name parameter
2. Replace zero(0) with your specific stash number. To get stash list, use:

   ```
   git stash list
   ```

Based on [Jakub Narębski's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1105666) -- Shorter version

Comment: You can also use the stash name `git checkout stash^{/'Stash name here'} -- <filename>`

Comment: This has two risks: (a) it will silently overwrite any unstaged local changes you have in this file; and (b) it copies the _exact_ file from the stash, without merging it with any changes that have been made on your branch since the stash was saved. That may be confusing since `git stash apply` / `pop` don't have either of those pitfalls. To get behavior that is more expected, use one of the `git diff`-based approaches in some of the other answers here.

Comment: Modern git versions: use `git restore --source=stash@{0} -- <filename>`

Answer (score 91):

If you use `git stash apply` rather than `git stash pop`, it will apply the stash to your working tree but still keep the stash.

With this done, you can `add`/`commit` the file that you want and then reset the remaining changes.

Comment: To pop a specific stash: `git stash pop stash@{0}` (list the stashed changes: `git stash list`)

Comment: If other files in the stash cause a merge conflict, git doesn't let me commit on the file I want :(

Comment: This is the best answer. You don't have to use a *diff*erent command (heh) to do what git stash apply should do, and you don't have to worry about any weird side effects (git checkout copies the exact file to the stash) or memorize any weird syntax.

Answer (score 49):

**Edit:** See [cambunctious's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59231358/315024), which is basically what I now prefer because it only uses the changes in the stash, rather than comparing them to your current state. This makes the operation additive, with much less chance of undoing work done since the stash was created.

To do it interactively, you would first do

```sh
git diff stash^! -- path/to/relevant/file/in/stash.ext perhaps/another/file.ext > my.patch
```

...then open the patch file in a text editor, alter as required, then do

```sh
git apply < my.patch
```

cambunctious's answer bypasses the interactivity by piping one command directly to the other, which is fine if you know you want all changes from the stash. You can edit the `stash^!` to be any commit range that has the cumulative changes you want (but check over the output of the diff first).

If applying the patch/diff fails, you can change the last command to `git apply --reject` which makes all the changes it can, and leaves `.rej` files where there are conflicts it can't resolve. The `.rej` files can then be applied using [`wiggle`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wiggle), like so:

```sh
wiggle --replace path/to/relevant/file/in/stash.ext{,.rej}
```

This will either resolve the conflict, or give you conflict markers that you'd get from a merge.

If your distro doesn't have `wiggle`, you can just build it:

```sh
cd /usr/local/src/
git clone git://git.neil.brown.name/wiggle
cd wiggle/
git checkout v1.3
make install
```

---

**Previous solution:** There is an easy way to get changes from any branch, including stashes:

```
$ git checkout --patch stash@{0} path/to/file
```

You may omit the file spec if you want to patch in many parts. Or omit patch (but not the path) to get all changes to a single file. Replace `0` with the stash number from `git stash list`, if you have more than one. Note that this is like `diff`, and offers to apply *all* differences between the branches. To get changes from only a single commit/stash, have a look at `git cherry-pick --no-commit`.

Comment: Does this copy the exact file from the stash, or does it merge? In case of copy, if you have any changes since the stash was created, they will be lost.

Comment: @Danijel Read `git help checkout`. `--patch` does interactive merging, It applies whatever hunk(s) you approve in the shell (or whatever you save if you choose to `e`dit the patch). Path alone will overwrite the file, like I wrote, "all changes".

Comment: slight improvement:  `git config --global alias.applydiffat '!git checkout --patch "$1" -- $(git diff --name-only "$1"^ "$1")'`  -- then doing `git applydiffat stash@{4}` only uses files that changed between the stash and its parent.

Answer (score 38):

### Short answer

To see the whole file: `git show stash@{0}:<filename>`

To see the diff: `git diff stash@{0}^1 stash@{0} -- <filename>`

Comment: I don't think s/he was concerned with viewing the stash for a particular file--only popping that file.

Comment: This is what I was looking for. Then you can replace `diff` with `difftool` to use your favourite external diff.

Comment: My git repo was corrupted but I had stashed the files, but couldn't apply because of the corruption. I was able to use this and pipe to a new file, diff it, and I was good to go. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

Use the following to apply the changes to a file in a stash to your working tree.

```
git diff stash^! -- <filename> | git apply
```

This is generally better than using `git checkout` because you won't lose any changes you made to file since you created the stash.

Comment: it is showing me this error: `error: No valid patches in input (allow with "--allow-empty")`

Comment: @user8395964 that means there are no changes to be applied (or the changes in the stash have already been applied)

Answer (score 11):

You can get the diff for a stash with "`git show stash@{0}`" (or whatever the number of the stash is; see "git stash list").  It's easy to extract the section of the diff for a single file.

Comment: Simpler still for minds like me: use `git show stash` to show the topmost stash (normally the only one you have). Similarly you can show the diff between your current branch and the stash with `git diff head stash`.

Answer (score 5):

The simplest concept to understand, although maybe not the best, is you have three files changed and you want to stash one file.

If you do `git stash` to stash them all, `git stash apply` to bring them back again and then `git checkout f.c` on the file in question to effectively reset it.

When you want to unstash that file run do a `git reset --hard` and then run `git stash apply` again, taking advantage ofthe fact that `git stash apply` doesn't clear the diff from the stash stack.

Answer (score 4):

For VS Code users, there is one method. Make sure to have [GitLens](https://gitlens.amod.io/) extension installed.

1. Go on `SOURCE CONTROL` tab
2. Click on `STASHES`.
3. You will be able to see available stashes.
4. Click on the desired stash.
5. Right click on the desired file which you want to unstash.
6. You will get 2 options, `Apply Changes` and `Restore (Checkout)`. You can click any of the options and you will get your file under `Changes` if you choose `Apply Changes` or `Staged Changes` if you choose `Restore (Checkout)`.

[image: unstash files from stash]

Answer (score 1):

If the stashed files need to merge with the current version so use the previous ways using diff. Otherwise you might use `git pop` for unstashing them, `git add fileWantToKeep` for staging your file, and do a `git stash save --keep-index`, for stashing everything except what is on stage.
Remember that the difference of this way with the previous ones is that it "pops" the file from stash. The previous answers keep it `git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>` so it goes according to your needs.