# See what's in a stash without applying it

Tags: git, git-stash

How do I see what is inside a [stash](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Stashing-and-Cleaning) without actually applying it?

Comment: He's not calling `stash` an application, he's referring to the act of applying the stash. Unclear terminology aside, the question is the same.

Comment: To get colorized diff output: `git stash show -p stash@{1} >~/.diff && vim ~/.diff` (doesn't have to be `vim`. any text editor as long as your text editor has syntax highlighting support for `diff` output).

Comment: @TrevorBoydSmith or just `git stash show -p stash@{1} | view -`

Comment: a little weird observation, on centos-7 `view` is aliased to `vi` and `man view` displays the man page for `vim`. (i'll have to change my `.bashrc` to use your new trick (it's better than my old way IMO).)

Comment: @AryehLeibTaurog: Assuming `view` is, as usual, equivalent to `vi` or `vim` in read-only mode, it can't read a file from standard input (it reads commands from stdin). `git stash show -p stash@{1} | less`

Comment: These two commands are awesome

git diff stash@{1}^!  

you will get the stash id from the git stash list command

 git stash list

Comment: git stash show <Stash Number>

Comment: Clearly this question and answer should be open and the other closed, just given the relative view counts and the succinct, comprehensive exchange. Food for SO thought.

Comment: `This question already has answers here:`

yeah whataver this one has better google rank and more upvotes but that one have better answer than overcomplicated manbook one like in this questiones

Comment: git stash show -p

Answer (score 3751, accepted):

From `man git-stash` (which can also be obtained via `git help stash`):

> The modifications stashed away by this command can be listed with `git stash list`, inspected with `git stash show`, and ...

```
show [<stash>]
    Show the changes recorded in the stash as a diff between the stashed
    state and its original parent. When no <stash> is given, shows the
    latest one. By default, the command shows the diffstat, but it will
    accept any format known to git diff (e.g., git stash show -p stash@{1}
    to view the second most recent stash in patch form).
```

Note: the `-p` option generates a *patch*, as per `git-diff` documentation.

List the stashes:

```
git stash list
```

Show the *files* in the most recent stash:

```
git stash show
```

Show the *changes* of the most recent stash:

```
git stash show -p
```

Show the *changes* of the named stash:

```
git stash show -p stash@{1}
```

Or in short:

```
git stash show -p 1
```

If you want to view changes of only the last stash:

```
git stash show -p 0
```

Comment: One very useful feature one may consider is to list contents of all local stashes:


`git stash list | awk -F: ‘{ print “\n\n\n\n”; print $0; print “\n\n”; system(“git –no-pager stash show -p ” $1); }’ | less`

It helped me a lot in the past (cleaning stashes stack).

Comment: Same command with fixed quotes and without piping to less so you can still see the diff highlighting:
`git stash list | awk -F: '{ print "\n\n\n\n"; print $0; print "\n\n"; system("git stash show -p " $1); }'` Press [Q] to exit each stash.

Comment: `git stash show -p stash@{1}` lists all the files in a stash. Is it possible to view jus one specific file from the stash?

Comment: For anyone skimming the "git stash show -p stash@{1} was what I was looking for" answer like me, {1} is the *2nd* stash, not the first. Numbering starts at 0.

Comment: I believe a simple `git show stash{0}` will get you the same result.

Comment: Same command with diff highlighting in a single less invocation: `git stash list | awk -F: '{ print "\n\n\n\n"; print $0; print "\n\n"; system("git -c color.ui=always stash show -p " $1); }' | less -R`

Comment: `git stash show -p -1`.  
This is equivalent to: `git stash show -p stash@{0}`, but shorter.

Comment: `git stash show -p stash@{0} --name-only` shows just the names of the files (not the contents) in your first stash.

Comment: git stash list  , should do it now

Comment: @ThalisK. I think you may have meant `git stash show stash@{0}`  Your version lacked the `stash` subcommand (there is no such thing as `git show`) and also the `@` sign.

Comment: @iconoclast, `git show stash@{0}` works as well (equivalent to `git stash show -p stash@{0}`). `stash@{0}` is a valid revision name.

Comment: Ah, interesting to know about that shorter way of accomplishing the same thing.  I tested Thalis's original version, but it didn't work because the `@` was missing.

Comment: If you're using [fish](http://fishshell.com), you need to escape the braces: `git stash show -p stash@\{0\}`

Comment: Note that this doesn't show added files!  See: [In git, is there a way to show untracked stashed files without applying the stash?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12681529/in-git-is-there-a-way-to-show-untracked-stashed-files-without-applying-the-stas)

Comment: `git stash show -p > ~/Desktop/stash.txt` outputs the diff to a file :P

Comment: @Gerry here's another way to get colorized diff output: `git stash show -p stash@{1} >~/.diff && vim ~/.diff` (doesn't have to be `vim`. any text editor as long as your text editor has syntax highlighting support for `diff` output).

Comment: `git stash show stash@{0}` shows the files that are modified. Add the `-p` flag to display the actual changes inside the files.

Comment: Interestingly, `git help stash` makes no mention of any available options for `git stash show`.

Comment: how to copy the change from stash ? .. i mean if i copy some lines from terminal it pastes with the punchuations like + which appears in beginning of each new line.

Comment: Is it possible to `git stash show -p` only for specific file?

Comment: @mrgloom If you want to see the stashed changes for a single file, then something like `git diff stash@{0}^! -- file.txt` will do it. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105253/how-would-i-extract-a-single-file-or-changes-to-a-file-from-a-git-stash) for more details.

Comment: `git stash show -p 0` works too.

Comment: Related if you got too many revision specified: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18884567/too-many-revisions-git-message

Comment: git stash show --stat

Comment: You can also use `stash@{n}` format in other places, e.g., `git show` to see the full stashed file (instead of diff), e.g., `git show stash@{0}:path/to/file`

Comment: this doesn't appear to show untracked files

Comment: @CervEd untracked files are not stashed

Comment: @click_whir they are if you include them

Comment: @CervEd I can't help you

Comment: This shows way more files than are actually in that stash.

Comment: @TobiasFeil It seems to me that any number in the stash list can be used to visualize a specific stash, e.g. `git stash show -p 2`

Comment: Not sure what triggers behind, but `git stash show --oneline` also shows the delta of a stash (without untracked files) on terminal.