# View git stash using visual tool

Tags: git, git-stash

We configure our diff visual tool using `diff.tool=xxx` and then running `git difftool` to see a visual diff.   [You can see](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10725729/git-see-whats-in-a-stash-without-applying-stash) a stash using `git stash show` - but how can you see the stash visually like you can with diff?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just use the stash's name. For example, the following works for me:

```
git diff branch stash@{0}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.  (replace diff with difftool to get the visual diff)

Comment: More thoughts on using diff to see stash @ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7677736/git-diff-against-a-stash?rq=1

Comment: @ObjectNameDisplay: Is your branch really named "branch"?

Comment: @ObjectNameDisplay: So use the name of the actual branch instead of `branch`.

Comment: I found: `git diff  stash@{0}` works quite well for the current branch.

Answer (score 0):

Using `git diff ..stash@{0}` (equivalent to the answer by @choroba) does not work well if the base branch of the stash is significantly different than your current branch.

A stash is essentially a merge commit so the most simple way to view the changes stored in a stash is `git show`:

```
git show stash@{0}
```

Which is roughly equivalent to this if you prefer to use `diff`:

```
git diff stash@{0}^..stash@{0}
```