# git remove file from stash

Tags: git, git-stash, merge-conflict-resolution

I have a stash with a bunch of files in it.

But I can't apply my stash because of a conflicting file. I've identified the problematic file in my stash and I want to remove it.

How can I remove a single file from a stash without destroying the entire thing?

Comment: This can help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105253/how-would-i-extract-a-single-file-or-changes-to-a-file-from-a-git-stash

Comment: @TimCastelijns So, from that answer, `$ git checkout stash@{0} -- <filename>` would be the command I want?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

A stash is a commit (or really, two or even sometimes three commits) and you cannot change a commit.  The literal answer to your question, then, is "you can't".  Fortunately, you don't *need* to.

You say you can't apply your stash because of a conflicting file.  But you *can* apply it, you just get a merge conflict.  All you need to do is resolve the merge conflict.

Let's say the conflict is in file `README.txt`, just so there's something to write about here.

If you want to resolve it by keeping the on-branch version, apply the stash, then check out the on-branch version to resolve the conflict:

```
git stash apply
git checkout --ours -- README.txt  # or git checkout HEAD -- README.txt
```

If you want to keep the in-stash version, extract that one:

```
git checkout --theirs -- README.txt # or git checkout stash -- README.txt
```

Or, use any old merge resolution tool (I just use a text editor), and then "git add" the result.

Once you are all done with the stash, `git stash drop` will "forget" the commits that make up the stash.  (Don't do this until you are sure you are done with it; it's very hard to get it back afterward.)

Comment: My error was that sourcetree wasn't letting me apply the stash because of a windows-specific error involving permissions and locked files. But this answers my question.

Comment: When attempting `git stash apply` I get an error due to the conflicts: `error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:`

Comment: @BergQuester: in this particular case, you're trying to `git stash apply` when you already have some existing change(s) in the work-tree.  Normally even that would be OK, so I'm not entirely sure what's happening (I'd need to see `git status` output before the `apply`, and what flags you're giving to `git stash apply`).  In general the way to handle this case, though, is to commit or stash the *current* changes, then use `git stash branch` to turn the previous stash into a new branch, and then use the full set of Git tools now that what you had stashed is safely stored as a branch.

Comment: Saying that you "cannot change a commit" is deceptive. You can amend a commit, which creates a copy with everything the same except the files and hash. So what's the equivalent to 'amend a stash'?

Comment: @MarkJeronimus: It's not deceptive: what's deceptive is the option `--amend` itself. You're not amending a commit at all. You're making a new, different commit, with a new, different hash; the old commit continues to exist, and is still used by all the *other* branch and tag names that find this commit (ideally there are zero such names, but when there aren't, that's when the deception is exposed). There's no "amend a stash" either, and this time there's no `--amend` flag: you just have to apply (with `--index` perhaps) the original stash in its original place, drop it, and build a new one.

Comment: That is, since `git stash` is a poor(ish, it's been improved) set of tools compared to all the regular Git tools, there's no fancy front end with a deceptive option like `git commit`'s `--amend`.  The closest one gets is `git stash branch`, which checks out the parent of the stash clump of commits, creates a new branch name, and then applies (with `--index`) the stash and drops it.

Answer (score 35):

There is a workaround for this situation:

1. save your stash as a patch file:

   ```
   $ git stash show -p > stash.patch
   ```
2. apply this patch, skipping the conflicts (you will be asked for resolution of conflicts, just skip missing files):

   ```
   $ patch -p1 < stash.patch
   ```

Don't forget to clean up `stash.patch` afterwards!

Comment: Straightforward solution

Comment: Thank you for this!

Comment: Don't forget to be in the root of your git repo or git will complain that it can't find files when you run the patch command!

Comment: very clean approach.

Comment: For windows users, the patch command fails in Cmd/Powershell. use git bash

Comment: I needed to add the _Reverse_ option (`-R`) to the `patch` command _->_ `patch -R -p1 < stash.patch`

Answer (score 4):

1. Stash your uncommitted changes.
2. Apply your original stash
3. Discard the file
4. 4 Apply the stash containing your uncommitted changes.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. I was working on a branch, stashed my modifications and wanted to apply them on another branch. But I noticed that I also stashed an unwanted file that created a conflict. Here's what I did to solve the issue:

- `git restore --staged path/to/file`
- `git reset HEAD -- path/to/file` to remove the file from the staging area

Then, I added the files I wanted only and was able to make my commit.

Answer (score -1):

delete the required file from your local codebase and then push it to stash. The changes will get reflected and your files will be deleted from stash.