# How to remove file from git stash

Tags: git, merge

I'm working on Branch A, then do "git stash" (with multiple files changed) and checkout branch B.  Changes are made and branch B is committed and pushed. Then "git stash pop" reports a merge conflict because a binary IDE file changed.

I don't want to merge a binary file. Just, how does one delete the original stashed binary file while retaining the other edited files?

Comment: Why not just deal with the conflict? It’s just asking you which version you want. Tell it and move on.

Comment: Matt's approach is the easiest. Otherwise you go the stash save, stay apply route, but it's a hassle.

Comment: Its a binary file.  Its very difficult to merge and not necessary. Either version is good. How to just select one version and use it?

Comment: Git tells you what to do. It doesn’t try to merge a binary file at all. It just declares the conflict and stops. It gives you clear instructions how to proceed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git remove file from stash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22722575/git-remove-file-from-stash)

Answer (score 1):

Technically, you *can't*.  The reason is simple: a stash is nothing but commits, and no commit can ever be altered.

As everyone noted in the comments, you don't need to remove this file.  An attempt to apply the stash will stop in the middle of the application with a merge conflict.  At this point, Git returns control to you; it becomes your job to select the correct merge result, in this case by selecting whichever binary file you prefer.

The tricky part is seeing which binary file is which.  The thing to know here is that the *stage 2* or `ours` (`--ours` in `git checkout`) file is the one that was in the working tree at the start of the merge.  The *stage 3* or `--theirs` file is the one in the stash; that's the file that was in place when you ran `git stash`.<sup>1</sup>  There is also a stage 1, or merge base, copy of the file, but you can ignore that one in this case: you will want the "ours" copy if you want the one you obtained via `git checkout B`, or the "theirs" copy if you want the one you stashed earlier.

It may be the case that the binary file should never have been in *any* of these commits (that's often the case for binary files: that they should never have been committed, that is).  Unfortunately, it is far too late, because of the fact that no existing commit can ever be changed.  So just go ahead and resolve the conflict first.  Later, you might look into making sure that *future* commits don't store these particular binary files, if they shouldn't.

---

<sup>1</sup>Technically, `git stash` makes *two* commits.  One of these two commits contains exactly what was in Git's *index* at the time you ran `git stash`.  This commit is completely ignored later *unless* you choose `--index` while applying it.  The other of the two commits contains the working tree copies of each of the files that was already in Git's index.  The `git stash apply` code always uses this commit (whether or not you use `--index` when applying).

To understand all of this, read up on how Git actually makes new commits from what is in Git's index, and how Git's index works.  This takes most people a fair bit of time when learning about Git, so don't worry if it doesn't "click" for a while.