# Is it possible to delete a single file (i.e the diff of one file) from git stash with several files

Tags: git, git-stash

I'm looking for a way to delete a single change from a stash compiled of several changes, anyone knows of a way to do it?
The best way for to describe it (due to the fact that `git commit` and `git stash` are so similar) is that I wish I knew a way to `git commit --amend` the stash.

It all started when I `git stash` a few changes before pulling from a shared repository.
while I was trying to `git pop` the code from the stash, I had a conflict (I couldn't resolve) with a file I didn't care for duo to the fact that I had a script to generate it automatically, and was more interested in the other files located in my stash.

While I was looking for a solution I've found this Q : [How would I extract a single file (or changes to a file) from a git stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105253/how-would-i-extract-a-single-file-or-changes-to-a-file-from-a-git-stash)  - it seemed promising, and was also given to someone else asking a similar question to mine, but it didn't help...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to delete a single change from a stash - at least not with the high-level commands that `git stash` provides. As a stash is internally just a commit, you could use the low-level commands to manipulate it, but that is likely more trouble than it is worth.

My rule of thumb is: If things start to get complicated with `git stash`, it's time to convert the stash to a real commit (typically on a separate branch). Then you can use all the nice git commands for manipulating commits (checkout, reset, rebase etc.).

In your case I'd recommend steps like this:

If `git stash pop` produces a conflict, clean up your working copy (re-checkout the files with conflict markers, etc.).

Then run:

```
git stash branch wip-branch
```

This will create and check out a new branch named "wip-branch", starting from the commit at which the stash was originally created. Then it will apply the changes from the stash. That way there cannot be a conflict, because the stashed changes are re-applied to the commit they are based on.

Now you have a real branch "wip-branch" with your stashed changes, which you can rebase, merge, cherry-pick etc. to your heart's content :-).

Note: While I used to use `git stash` regularly, I have almost stopped, because creating a real (temporary) commit on a real branch is not much more work, and gives me more options (not to mention that I can use proper commit comments, so I don't forget what the changes mean).

Comment: More detailed than my answer. I like the branch approach. +1

Comment: @VonC: Thanks. Actually (as you can see from edit history), I used to manually create the branch and apply the stash. Answering this question motivated me to read the git-stash manpage, and I found that git-stash actually has a command to convert a stash to a branch. "To teach is to learn", as the proverb goes.

Comment: Good catch! `git stash branch` FTW!

Comment: @sleske, thanks! i hope i won't have to use your solution, i've already cleared the stash (by accident while trying some "voodoo  command" combined with what was written in the Q i linked) cause my code was needed by other people (shared repository).

anyway, you can add a message/comment to your stash...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is easier to:

- apply your stash
- git checkout the file with conflict (to reset it, ignoring any conflict in it)
- git stash again