# View diff contents of 1 specific stashed file in Git

Tags: git, diff, git-stash, git-show

Let's say I have 2 stashed files:

```
$ git stash show

a.txt | 2 +-
b.txt | 2 +-
2 files changed, 2 insertions(+), 2 deletions(-)
```

I can view the complete diff of the stash:

```
diff --git a/a.txt b/a.txt
index bc56c4d..a688182 100644
--- a/a.txt
+++ b/a.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Foo
+Baz
diff --git a/b.txt b/b.txt
index ebd7525..4105321 100644
--- a/b.txt
+++ b/b.txt
@@ -1 +1 @@
-Bar
+Qux
```

More files would clutter the output, so I want to view only 1 specific file. However, the manual appears to say there isn't an option for using a filename argument:

> ```
> NAME
>        git-stash - Stash the changes in a dirty working directory away
>
> SYNOPSIS
>        ...
>        git stash show [<stash>]
>        ...
> ```

Is there a way to view the diff contents of only 1 specific stashed file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Building on [How would I extract a single file (or changes to a file) from a git stash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1105253/how-would-i-extract-a-single-file-or-changes-to-a-file-from-a-git-stash) you could:

`git diff stash@{0}^! -- a.txt`

Comment: Perfect, exactly what I needed.