# How to revert a file in Git that has been renamed

Tags: git

I'd like to revert a file that has been renamed, say it's now called B, to what it was in an earlier commit, say it was called A, how would I do this while still preserving the history? File B has been pushed.

I can see the entire history of file B, including when it was named A, using:

`git log --follow pathToFileB`

This shows me a list of commits which this file was involved in, but I'm not sure what to do from there.

Normally, I'd do `git checkout commitId:pathToFile`, but this doesn't seem to work in this case.

Comment: Would it be a problem just to rename it back to A and commit?

Answer (score 4):

You can overwrite file B with the old contents of file A with:

```
git show commitId:pathToFileA > pathToFileB
```

You can read more in this answer to a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/a/888623/4231110