# Accessing binary premodified file before commiting

Tags: git, binary, diff

Suppose we have a git repository that contains two images: `alice.png` and `bob.png`. We commited this in `Initial commit`.

After that, we do `cp bob.png alice.png`, so `alice.png` will have the same content with `bob.png`.

Doing `git diff` shows that.

Now if I open `alice.png` I see Bob. How can I open/read/access programatically the old `alice.png` (which appears if I do `git checkout alice.png`)?

---

The best (which is not a good one) solution I found is to:

- copy the repository into a temp directory
- do `git checkout .`
- get modified files from original directory
- read the non-modified files from temp directory

But I suppose there should be a better solution.

---

For non-binary files [`git show HEAD:path/to/file` does this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/888414/1420197), but for me, when doing `git show HEAD:alice.png` nothing is output.

Comment: possible duplicate of [git-checkout older revision of a file under a new name](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/888414/git-checkout-older-revision-of-a-file-under-a-new-name)

Comment: @CarlNorum Seems the correct solution, but I get this error: `fatal: Path '1.png' exists on disk, but not in 'HEAD^'.`

Comment: You don't want `HEAD^` in your case, just `HEAD`. You could also use the hash of your `Initial commit`. The point is to specify a revision that includes the file you want to check out. If you have only one commit, you don't even *have* a `HEAD^`.

Comment: @CarlNorum `git show HEAD:alice.png > old_alice.png` -- `old_alice.png` and `git show HEAD:alice.png` doesn't output anything (probably because it's a binary file?).

Comment: @CarlNorum I updated my question reflecting this thing.

Comment: I can't replicate this. `git show HEAD:alice.png > foo.png` works for me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access a file at a given commit with `git show`. Since your changes are still uncommitted, the old file is still at `HEAD`.

```bash
# This opens a file in the pager
git show HEAD:path/to/file

# Save the file to disk
git show HEAD:alice.png > temp.png
```

If you have an image viewer that supports piping on stdin such as ImageMagick's `display`, you could view the image directly.

```bash
git show HEAD:alice.png | display
```

Comment: When I tried it, my pager showed a bunch of binary garbage (the encoded image). Your default pager for git is probably ignoring the binary file content. Did you try saving the file and opening that in your image viewer?

Comment: Yes, I tried. But since `>` just redirects the output, it created an empty file.

Comment: That's strange. Do you get the same results with `bob.png`?

Comment: According to the [git-show manual](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-show.html), the contents of a blob shouldn't matter, so the image format difference is confusing. Just to eliminate any extra factors, try `git --no-pager show:alice.png`. This should output the binary contents to stdout. If that doesn't work, I would double check that the committed file is correct.