# git checkout a single file from another branch and put in different folder

Tags: git

I am trying to `git checkout` a single file from another branch.

Everything is fine, but it puts the file in the same directory tree of the branch that I am checking out.

There is a way to specify a different destination folder during git checkout?

This is what I did:

```
git checkout other_branch -- path/to/file/xxx
```

git status:

```
new file:             path/to/file/xxx
```

this the result I need (put xxx into the root directory of my working branch):

```
new file:             ./xxx
```

Comment: Can you explain why you want to check out a file in a different path? You say, "in the root directory of my working branch." In a Git repo, different branches exist in the same directory. It seems like you may be using Git in a way that it was not designed for.

Comment: This answer involving git show is the right one, IMO https://stackoverflow.com/a/888623/192737

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have 2 options

1. chain 2 commands, `git checkout other_branch -- file.txt && git mv file.txt folder/file.txt`
2. or you can use [worktree](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-worktree)

Comment: Note that this overwrites and removes the old `file.txt` in the current branch.

Comment: Is the path to the file relative to the repository root folder?

Answer (score 4):

You should be able to just move the file, e.g. in Linux, from your working directory:

```
mv path/to/file/xxx ./xxx
```

You would then have to stage the changes resulting from the system move command.  You may also try using `git mv`:

```
git mv path/to/file/xxx ./xxx
```

Using `git mv` should also take care of the staging work for you.

Answer (score 4):

The previous answers overwrite the file we are checking out. To avoid this we can use `git show` according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56029554/8571434) and Jeff Trull's comment to the question.

```
git show other_branch:path/to/file/xxx > xxx
```

`git show other_branch:path/to/file/xxx` outputs the file contents to stdout and `> xxx` redirects that output to the file `xxx` instead.

Comment: This has already been suggested in Jeff Trull's comment.