# Git alias for git checkout older revision file as new file name

Tags: git, command-line-interface

I want to have a new git alias with which I can checkout file(s) from an older revision under new file name(s).

I have a git alias for showing log saved in my C:\Users\nguyen\.gitconfig

```
[user]
name = Tin Nguyen
email = xx@xx.com

[diff]
tool = winmerge

[difftool "winmerge"]
cmd = "'C:/Program Files (x86)/WinMerge/WinMergeU.exe'" -e "$LOCAL" "$REMOTE"

[alias]
    alog = log --all --decorate --oneline --graph
```

I tried to apply what I had with difftool but somehow I kept getting the syntax wrong.

Here a question was answered how to git checkout a file under a new file name: [git-checkout older revision of a file under a new name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/888414/git-checkout-older-revision-of-a-file-under-a-new-name)

```
git show 4c274dd91dc:higgs/Higgs.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj > old_project.pbxproj
prompt>
```

I want to be able to write:

```
git smartout 4c274dd91dc oldname.py as newname.py
```

Comment: I very much doubt any alias will be shorter or simpler than the `git show` command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
git config --global alias.smartout '!f() { !git show $1:$3 > $2; }; f'
```

then

```
git smartout 4c274dd91dc fullpath/to/oldname.py fullpath/to/newname.py
```

*(As a sidenote, mind the small word "as" which I stripped from your desired format, because it was bringing a lot of trouble, for the only "benefit" of making each use a bit longer to type. [phd's doubts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56890136/git-alias-for-git-checkout-older-revision-file-as-new-file-name/56890219#comment100328130_56890136) about the alias' usefulness would be even more accurate with an additional word here.)*